# Problems about Decision Tree

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

Do any one give me some hints to solve this problem. Explain is steps by steps.Thanks[image]

Comment: The first step is estimating the Gini index in each of the two regions for each of the two splits (four in total). Can you do that?

Comment: Is I correct? for (a) the Gini index is 0 for the lowest part, 0.4*0.5+0.5*0.4=0.4 for the upper part

Comment: I’m not going to check your calculations. You asked for guidance, so I explained what you need to do. I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks.  After calculate the Gini index, what I am going to do?

Comment: Read the question carefully and come up with an answer.